# How do I activate the link if it is worth 1, if it is 0 then link is not active use radio button

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My controller

```
$data['registrasi'] = $this->pengumuman->getRegistrasi($id_pengumuman);
```

To my model. I try to make

```
public function getRegistrasi($id_pengumuman) //1 = active link, 0 = not active
    {
        if($cek == 1 ){
        $link = 'e-beasiswa/Registrasibeasiswa';
        }else{
            $tidak = 'nonaktif';
        }
        echo $link;
    }
```

My view

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12" >
  <label>Buka Pendaftaran<span class="required">*</span></label>
   <div class="icheck-list"><br>
   <label>
    <input type="radio" class="icheck" name="is_registrasi" id="is_registrasi" value="1" <?= ($registrasi->is_registrasi == '1') ? "checked":""; ?> >Ya</label>
   <label>
    <input type="radio" class="icheck" name="is_registrasi" id="is_registrasi" value="0" <?= ($registrasi->is_registrasi == '0') ? "checked":""; ?> >Tidak</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

my detail.php

```
<a href=""><?= $registrasi->is_registrasi ?></a>
```

on my form using the radio button, to choose whether the link appears or not.

note: the link will be displayed on page detail

Comment: What is the difference between 'my view' and 'my detail' are they both in the same page? You want when someone clicks the radio button with value of 1 then the link activates? Sounds like a javascript issue to me and not a ci/php one...

Comment: Yes, im sory my english so bad.
I have two pages, first the index page to display all announcement data, the second detail page of each announcement. the link will appear on the detail page along with the details of the announcement.

Answer (score 0):

Put the html link code in a php ternary operator. The link is only visible if `$registrasi->is_registrasi` is equals to 1.

You can try **this code**:

```
<?php echo $registrasi->is_registrasi == '1' ? '<a href="#">'.$registrasi->is_registrasi.'</a>' : ''; ?>
```